# Большие пустые области с обеих сторон графика (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Сейчас работаю над скриптом, выдающим статистику посещений одного игрового сервера. Реализую визуализацию самого графика через библиотеку matplotlib, язык Python. Всё бы ничего, но график по какой-то причине растянут в обе стороны, причем изнутри (прикрепил скрин). Мешает восприятию информации. В чём может быть проблема? Весь интернет облазил, ничего не пишут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код и часть данных:

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Пример данных ниже
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

x = data.keys()
y = data.values()

ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=15)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=15)

plt.grid(True)

plt.yticks(range(0, 25+1))
plt.xticks(list(data.keys()), rotation=45)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(len(data.keys())*0.6, 13)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('grafic.jpg', pad_inches = 0.5)
```

Ссылка на полный пакет данных, при которых проявляется артефакт: https://pastebin.com/YZctZqYR

Comment: Без данных и кода можно только гадать. Для начала попробуйте поставить в конце `plt.tight_layout()`. Дальше можно попробовать задать границы оси через `plt.xlim`

Comment: @CrazyElf plt.tight_layout() вроде с полями разбирается, а не с положением на осях, но могу врать

Comment: @splash58 пусть попробует, хуже не будет )

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` не сработало

Comment: С приведёнными вами данными такого эффекта не наблюдается.

Comment: За выставление сюда кода с синтаксическими ошибками -  т.е. человек даже не удосужился свой код запустить для проверки -  я бы нещадно банил.  Ваш код, стока plt.yticks(range(0, max_online+1))   -  какое значение имеет переменная max_online????

Comment: @passant Удосужился, просто взял часть кода из общей системы. Переменная равна 25, это что-то кардинально меняет? Тем более, что это видно на прикрепленной картинке

Comment: @CrazyElf Вообще, когда данных гораздо больше (00:05, 00:10 и так за весь день), тогда и проявляется артефакт

Comment: @Metanol Выложите данные, на которых проявляется этот эффект куда-нибудь и дайте ссылку. Без данных, на которых проявляется ошибка, мы вообще по правилам не должны на вопрос отвечать )

Comment: Ага, вот теперь эффект вижу. Интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я и предполагал, задание `xlim` исправляет ситуацию:

```
plt.xlim(-1, len(data))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь